# Better add images through html or css?

Tags: html, css, image

Better add images through HTML and determine `alt` tags, or add through CSS with the `text-indent: -9999px` (or similar) property? Or is there no difference?

Does search engines take `text-indent: -9999px` property as a normal way of doing things? Cause with this property we actually create a text, but not showing it for the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it depends on what you're trying to make it mean. Is it an image with text fallback, or is it text with an image enhancement?

If I have an image which is just a fancier version of the text (perhaps with special effects or flourishes), I use the text with `background-image` and negative `text-indent`. If I have an image where the text does *not* convey the *full* meaning, I use `<img alt>`.

Comment: +1. To add to what Chris said, HTML is a semantic language, so that's the reasoning behind his thoughts, I'd imagine.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: that's it.  Well put.